# Use System Restore to rescue lost user profile in Win XP?

Tags: windows-xp, system-restore

My Windows XP account profile has recently been "reset".

Many of my application settings have been lost. For example, the "recent project" list in VS 2005 is empty. There should be lots of other settings, but they are now painfully lost without me knowing!

What can I do? Can I retrieve the lost application settings using System Restore?

I don't have much confidence on this utility, even though I think restoring to a point when the profile still works, and back up the `C:\Documents and Settings` (is it where all the app setting files are located?), that should work...?

Is it reliable to restore to a previous restore point and then return to the latest restore point?

I've searched on Google about System Restore, it looks like what the utility does is just back up some physical files and restore them when performing a system restore. That sounds quite safe, but I am still uncomfortable to this.

Answer (score 1):

Do the system restore. It is very safe and works pretty will.  The more recent the restore point the better. Start by restoring at the point right before you lost these files and then work backwards if the first one doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

System restore cannot really damage your data.
Mostly, the system restore is not that effective (I can tell from my experience with that tool), but it worth to give it a try - it might help you.

Next time, just make sure that you're saving the important data and settings in your PC.

Best of luck,
Matan.